# scanf vs getchar in c using recursion

Tags: c, scanf

This is a code to 'print in reverse' the characters entered for two cases, one with scanf and another with getchar. getchar gives the correct answer whereas scanf shows segmentation fault

```
#include <stdio.h>
void reverse()
{
    char ch;
    scanf("%c",&ch); /*or ch=getchar;*/
    if(ch==EOF){
        return;
    }
    reverse();
    printf("%c",ch);
}
int main()
{
    reverse();
    return 0;
} 
/*input -- code work    output -- krow edoc*/
```

Can anyone please explain the error and what is happening behind the scenes?

Thank you!

scanf -- segmentation fault
getchar -- correct answer

Comment: `scanf` does not place `EOF` in the target variable. It returns `0` as the function value when the input fails, but you have ignored what `scanf` returns. Try `if(scanf("%c", &ch) != 1) return;` or `if(scanf(" %c", &ch) != 1) return;` to skip whitespace.

Comment: @WeatherVane More like `scanf()` returns `EOF` on end-of-file or input error.  I see no case where `scanf("%c",&ch);` returns 0.

Comment: @chux-Reinstate Monica `scanf` certainly doesn't place `EOF` in the target variable. The safe course is to check the specific return value (only `1` is a good result) rather than envisage possibilities.

Comment: @WeatherVane Agrees that checking against 1 is preferable, yet since `scanf("%c",&ch);` does not return 0, "It returns 0 as the function value when the input fails," is not relevant to OP's case that is certainly looking for end-of-file.  IOWs, right answer, non-applicable explanation.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica yes, it would be truer to say that `scanf` returns `0` when the conversion fails, not the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Wrong test**

When end-of-file occurs `scanf("%c",&ch)` returns `EOF`, not set `ch` to `EOF`.

Check the return value against the *desired goal* of 1 (meaning 1 conversion succeeded.) and not against other possible return value(s) like `EOF`.

```
char ch;

//scanf("%c",&ch); /*or ch=getchar;*/
//if(ch==EOF){
if (scanf("%c",&ch) != 1) {

    return;
}
```